# New activity for fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm following the google maps tutorial for Android here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

My question is, once I get to the 'Add a map' section, is that code for my fragment's java? Or the main java that was for the first part?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it the same for your main java file which will be your main activity file.

You can add the map at any activity or fragment you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
the doc clearly says that 
"
Add a <fragment> element to your activity's layout file, activity_maps.xml.  "

so the the "activity_maps.xml" is the activity layout file and the following code should be inside the "activity_maps.xml"


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace" />
```

refer the this link if you find it helpful

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314635/android-map-in-fragment
```

Comment: I'm talking about the java

Comment: @samuelJohnson ..sorry i was lost in your question..yes..its for your activity java file